# C++ static member modifiers for subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, field

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

/// Header-file
class Base {
public:
  virtual void do_something() const =0;

  int GetAttrib () const {return constattribute_;};

  static const int constattribute_;
};

typedef Base* Derived_Ptr; //<< adress derived classes by their base-class ptr; so no templates for Base

class DerivedA : public Base {
//   static const int constattribute_; //<< change this static attribute for all DerivedA class instances and their derivatives

  void do_something() const {};
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
//   static const int constattribute_; //<< change this static attribute for all DerivedB class instances and their derivatives

  void do_something() const {};
};

/// CC-file
using namespace std;

const int Base::constattribute_(0);
const int DerivedA::constattribute_(1); //<<error: no such variable 'constattribute' in class DerivedA
const int DerivedB::constattribute_(2); //<<error: no such variable 'constattribute' in class DerivedB


int main(void) {
  Derived_Ptr derivedA = new DerivedA();
  Derived_Ptr derivedB = new DerivedB();

  cout << derivedA->GetAttrib() << derivedB->GetAttrib() <<endl;
  return 0;
};
```

The intend being that i have some abstract interface (Base) which defines also a variable, which should be present for all derived classes, and is retrievable. All flavours of subclasses should be forced to/able to redefine their specific value for this variable, at best during class declaration (the values are known at the time the class is declared after all).

I want to achieve code, not altering the main()-program so that the output is '12' and not as of now (uncommenting current lines in the code) '00' (Doing so shadows the fields from base class).

I tried to look into the matter, and there are different paths for solutions, many of which however go contrary to my intuition: 
1. Some follow the CRTP pattern, which is however impossible if I want to address my subclasses by their base-ptr in main.
2. Other solutions require to virtualize the 'GetAttrib()' function for every derived instance., which is cumbersome, and action of modifying the attribute is masked within a function definition.
3. A third possibility is to remove the static pattern and have the 'constattribute_' field as a regular member, which however forces me to drag it through all constructors as a parameter.

I am quite sure that there must be some smarter way to do this. Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CRTP may get you what you want, assuming you don't have to access GetAttr() through Base* and can leave without constattribute_ in Base itself. Just follow the rule that every programming problem can be solved by entering another level of indirection, which I did below:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void do_something() const = 0;

    virtual ~Base()     // should define it as you are using Base*
    {
    }
};

typedef Base* Derived_Ptr;

template<class T>
class BaseConstAttr : public Base
{
  public:
    int GetAttrib () const
    {
      return(constattribute_);
    };

    static const int constattribute_;
};

class DerivedA : public BaseConstAttr<DerivedA>
{
  public:
    void do_something() const
    {
    };
};

class DerivedB : public BaseConstAttr<DerivedB>
{
  public:
    void do_something() const
    {
    };
};

template<> const int BaseConstAttr<DerivedA>::constattribute_(1);
template<> const int BaseConstAttr<DerivedB>::constattribute_(2);
```

If you need GettAttr from top to bottom of the inheritance tree you can modify the above code a bit, but this will cost you making GetAttr virtual (but still one implementation only):

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void do_something() const = 0;
    virtual int GetAttrib () const = 0;

    virtual ~Base()     // should define it as you are using Base*
    {
    }
};

typedef Base* Derived_Ptr;

template<class T>
class BaseConstAttr : public Base
{
  public:
    int GetAttrib () const
    {
      return(constattribute_);
    };

    static const int constattribute_;
};

class DerivedA : public BaseConstAttr<DerivedA>
{
  public:
    void do_something() const
    {
    };
};

class DerivedB : public BaseConstAttr<DerivedB>
{
  public:
    void do_something() const
    {
    };
};

template<> const int BaseConstAttr<DerivedA>::constattribute_(1);
template<> const int BaseConstAttr<DerivedB>::constattribute_(2);
```

Please note that I don't know how well (or bad) it will behave with deep inheritance tree (ie. when inheriting from DerivedA and/or DerivedB). In this case I would probably remove BaseConstAttr from inheritance tree right below Base and would try to inject it between most derived class and its predecessor or use multiple inheritance.

Comment: Interesting approach. Note that, rather than specializing `BaseConstAttr` for each type and using the CRTP, you could instead pass the value of the attribute in a template argument (`template <int A> class BaseConstAttr ...`) and then you have a single `template<int A> const int BaseConstAttr<A>::constattribute_{A};`. Then `DerivedA` can inherit `BaseConstAttr<1>` and `DerivedB` can inherit `BaseConstAttr<2>` and that's all you have to do to make it work!

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks! Side note: even though I understand how the compiler needs to resolve the paths to the static variables, this makes it necessary to implement the CRTP pattern after defining the Base-class interface. So my tree of derivatives gets one level deeper for every each subclass, where `class BaseConstAttrib` just extends the interface of `class Base` a little bit by something which I thought could be achieved right at the point where `Base` is declared and defined (I do not intend to diverge from the so outlined interface in any of the subclasses).

Comment: Working a little bit further through this: as now DerivedA and DerivedB directly inherit from `BaseConstAttrib`>>`Base` you will have to re-broadcast all custom constructors of  `Base` (they will effectively be inlined I guess). This is the trade-off against the virtual inheritance from a separate `BaseConstAttrib` virtually inheriting from `Base` and deriving from it on every implementing subclass (one needs to remember to include this separate interface component).

Comment: Doing template on int A as cdhowie suggested can have additional advantage that the static const constattrib_ can be dropped altogether if its only purpose is to be used in GetAttr method, which can then refer directly to template parameter. Constructors can be imported at any point in inheritance tree by using and additional template parameter which will specify the base class. This has a drawback that all of them will either be public, private or protected.

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting requires virtual dispatch *somewhere*, because you don't know the type of the object you are dealing with until runtime.  The purpose of virtual dispatch is to solve exactly the problem you are facing.

The simplest solution is what you have given as number 2: make `GetAttrib()` virtual, and implement it on each derived class where you introduce a shadowing `constattribute_`.

Answer (score 0):

static variable in base class is single instance hence it will be reflected same in derived class.

You can make same static member variable in derived class with specific different value you want. Now make getter member function of static variable in Base class as virtual and overload it in derived class which returns is static instance value.

I have update your code to work it, please check ..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
  static const int constattribute_;
  virtual void do_something() const =0;
  virtual int GetAttrib () const {return constattribute_;};
};

typedef Base* Derived_Ptr; //<< adress derived classes by their base-class ptr; so no templates for Base

class DerivedA : public Base {
  static const int constattribute_; //<< change this static attribute for all DerivedA class instances and their derivatives

  void do_something() const {};
  int GetAttrib () const {return constattribute_;};
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
  static const int constattribute_; //<< change this static attribute for all DerivedB class instances and their derivatives

  void do_something() const {};
  int GetAttrib () const {return constattribute_;};
};

const int Base::constattribute_(0);
const int DerivedA::constattribute_(1); //<<error: no such variable 'constattribute' in class DerivedA
const int DerivedB::constattribute_(2); //<<error: no such variable 'constattribute' in class DerivedB


int main(void) {
  Derived_Ptr derivedA = new DerivedA();
  Derived_Ptr derivedB = new DerivedB();

  cout << derivedA->GetAttrib() << derivedB->GetAttrib() <<endl;

  return 0;
};
```

You should get desired output.

Note : Remember all member variables and func in derived class are private.

Comment: Your answer is valid to the point that I will get the desired output, and outlines what I proposed as solution path (2). However the price is a lot of reimplementation `GetAttrib()` in each one of the subclasses. Following your solution, in principle I could also move the _local_, _shadowing_ `constattribute_`variable from each subclass into its function definition as a plain return value. This would as I say hide the true behavior of the class as an implementation detail, instead of having it as a static property of the subclass itself.